# Arduino Control TV over RS232

Tags: arduino-uno, digital, nodemcu, rs232

I have a LG TV(LG 32SL800 ZB), which has a RS232-Port for Control and Service.

And I am wondering if I could control this port with my Arduino (NODE-MCU) and a module like this one [RS232 Board](http://www.waveshare.com/rs232-board.htm)?

How could I then control the TV? This is the [Manual](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_ayS6QBJX3VR2V1X1VxRlloZm8) for the TV at page 124 there are the commands how to control it, but how can I send them?

My last question is, how long can the cables from the arduino to the module be? They have to be about 2-3m long! Is that possible without any other hardware?

Answer (score 1):

> And I am wondering if I could control this port with my Arduino (NODE-MCU) and a module like this one?

Yes, you can, though choose a board based around the MAX3232 for a 3.3V MCU board.

> How could I then control the TV? This is the Manuel for the TV at page 124 there are the commands how to control it, but how can I send them?

Exactly as they show in the manual. For example:

```
Serial.print("ka 0 01\r");
```

That would turn on every TV connected to the serial bus.

> My last question is, how long can the cables from the arduino to the module be? They have to be about 2-3m long! Is that possible without any other hardware?

You can get away with no more than maybe 1 meter between the Arduino and the RS232 board. Keep that as short as possible. However between the RS232 board and the TV you can have up to 15 meters of cable.

Comment: I now have tried the commands! The "ka 01 00\r" which should turn on the TV works perfectly but any other command doesn't work?